# An error about "make_shared",I can't understand

Tags: c++

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<new>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
using std::vector;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    shared_ptr<vector<int> > pointer=make_shared<vector<int>> ({2,3,5,8});
    cout<<(*pointer)[3];
    return 0;
```

**so make_shared can't initialize like ({2,3,5,8}),why?**
    }

Answer (score 0):

The function `make_shared` cannot forward intializer lists. If you need to use an initializer list constructor, you have to invoke the `shared_ptr` constructor directly.

Comment: Or explicitly write `std::inititializer_list<int>{2, 3, 5, 8}`